# ExtJs 4 Grid with nested grouping

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

**Is there an official way to implement nested grouping in extjs grids?**

Let's say I have a bunch of models that I've grouped **per employee**, so far so good, now those reccords have a status, and **I need to group by status also.**

I've found this extension:

http://jaffa.sourceforge.net/JaffaRIATests/tests/extjs/multigroup/MultiGroup.html

Is there any other way?

Would it be a better aproach to use RowExpander?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just found this extension: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265814-Multi-level-grouping-summary-and-grand-totals-for-Ext-JS-4.2
seems very promising! (I'll be back to share results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This UX worked perfectly.**

I'll try to share an example in sencha fiddle with less code than in this post.

Best regards.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265814-Multi-level-grouping-summary-and-grand-totals-for-Ext-JS-4.2